# another problem with context using package and association when using Inactivate

Tags: evaluation, hold

This problem is similar to this [problem using package to verify solution of ode with Association, Naming scope/context handling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278324/problem-using-package-to-verify-solution-of-ode-with-association-naming-scope-c) but when I used the solution/trick given there, I still get a problem.

I am not well versed in low level package programming to figure what other tricks I need for this and it seems the solutions are way too complicated for me to understand.

Here is MWE. Given this package

```
BeginPackage["mypkg`"] 

Unprotect @@ Names["mypkg`*"]; 
ClearAll @@ Names["mypkg`*"]; 

dsolve::usage = "..."

Begin["`Private`"]     

    dsolve[y_,x_]:= Module[{assoc},
        assoc=<| "x"->x,"y"->y|>;
        process[assoc]
    ];           

    process[assoc_Association]:=Module[{x,y},
        x=assoc["x"];
        y=assoc["y"];
        Inactivate[Integrate[1/Log[1+K[1]^2],{K[1],0,y[x]}]]
    ];

End[]; 
Protect @@ Names["mypkg`*"]; 
EndPackage[]
```

And now

```
 SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
 Get["mypkg.m"]
 mypkg`dsolve[y, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution given in the above link is to use `@@ List[...]` instead. So I replaced the line

```
 Inactivate[Integrate[1/Log[1+K[1]^2],{K[1],0,y[x]}]]
```

with

```
 Inactivate @@ List[Integrate[1/Log[1+K[1]^2],{K[1],0,y[x]}]]
```

And this did indeed fix the context issue, but now I get a new problem

```
 Get["mypkg.m"]
 mypkg`dsolve[y, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see, it tried to do the integration.

What I want is to use `Inactivate` to prevent the integral from evaluating but without the `Private` context showing up. i.e. I want the above output but with Mathematica actually doing the integral and getting this error, as I know this integral can't be integrated.

I am doing this so I can replace the form of the unevaluated integral to one with the upper limit being $y(x)$ as this is the form I prefer.

Any other tricks I should try?

V 13.2 on windows.

Comment: Here is it not about renaming but controlling evaluation, you need e.g. `With[{upper = y[x]}, Inactivate[Integrate[1/Log[1 + K[1]^2], {K[1], 0, upper}]] ]` like you would in `x = 1; Hold[x]`

Comment: @Kuba thanks, this worked. But isn't `Inactivate` supposed not to evaluate what is inside it in first place? Or does it evaluate some parts on its arguments first?  may be I misunderstood `Inactivate` Note that in Global context this works as is without having to do `With` trick. i.,e. `Inactivate[Integrate[1/Log[1 + K[1]^2], {K[1], 0, y[x]}]]` works with no error. That is why I thought it is related to naming/context issue.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsL01.png)  I do not think I will ever be able to understand fully Mathematica's evaluation/naming/contexts mixing...

Comment: @Kuba may be you can make this an answer, but with explanation of why `With` is needed inside the package and not needed outside the package as I am not able to figure it out myself. Thanks.

Comment: "in Global context this works as is without having to do `With` trick" No, the problem is still there. The following should help you see what's wrong: `x = xx; y = yy; Inactivate[Integrate[1/Log[1 + K[1]^2], {K[1], 0, y[x]}]]`. Also, if you just want to stop `Integrate`, it's better to write `Inactivate[Integrate[1/Log[1 + K[1]^2], {K[1], 0, y[x]}], Integrate]` (otherwise `Inactivate` will make *almost* every head `Inactive`) or simply `Inactive[Integrate][1/Log[1 + K[1]^2], {K[1], 0, y[x]}]`. These avoid the mentioned issue, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not really related to context although you see a full name of `y` because `process` was defined in that context and `Module's` `y` was parsed there. Not important really.

Even `Module` is not important although it manifests here in a `$nnnnn` number in the symbol name.

So let's strip package and Module from the case, and let's rename `x`, `y` to `var` and `foo` to avoid confusion from the fact that you have

```
local`x = <|"x" -> global`x|>
```

The issue boils down to the fact that `Inactivate` holds the whole expression initially and later keeps heads (`foo`/`y`) held. So those heads will stay as you specified them:

```
a = <|"x" -> x, "y" -> y|>;
var = a["x"];
foo = a["y"];
Inactivate[foo[var] + foo[var]] // InputForm
```

> `Inactive[Plus][Inactive[foo][x], Inactive[foo][x]]`

We need to force evaluation but in many cases, like in yours, we need to be careful not to evaluate too much. There are many ways:

```
Inactivate[#[var] + #[var]] & @ foo

Inactivate[foo[var] + foo[var]] /. HoldPattern[foo] -> foo
```

but `With` is the most verbose I guess:

```
With[{foo = foo},
  Inactivate[foo[var] + foo[var]]
] // InputForm
```

Notice this is the same trick used with `Dynamic` programming:

- https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html#2125133640

See also:

- closely related: [Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/5478)
- related: [scoping construct use cases](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/5478)